# Зависит ли keycode от раскладки клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript

Есть текстовое поле, хочу сделать так чтоб в него можно было вбивать только цифры.

Нашёл пример как это сделать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery).

Но есть проблема: у меня отличаются keycode клавиши.

Например n = 102, а должна быть 78.

**Вопрос:** почему так? Может всё зависит от кодировки/раскладки? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не знаю зачем вам клавиша n.  [Ваша задача в решении](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/numeric-input)

Comment: Отлично. Условие: if ((event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) { // && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)}
            event.preventDefault(); нажимаю клавишу b она возвращает мне keycode 98, и она считается у меня цифрой! n я для примера написал, у меня в принципе все keycode'ы другие.

Comment: `<input type="number" />` не пробовали?

Comment: это html5, мне нужно с поддержкой ie7

Comment: Только что проверил keyCode здесь — 78 в обоих раскладках. В каком браузере у вас 102? Может, использовать `e.which`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, раскладка и удержание клавиши shift влияет на keyCode.
Лучше использовать свойство which, т.к. в firefox'e keyCode возвращает ноль.

Вот пример

```js
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

inp.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Только цифры">
```

Также как вариант можно использовать маску - [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Пример

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $("#digits").mask("999999999",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="digits" placeholder="Только цифры">
```

Но нужно указывать количество символов для ввода.

Попробуйте эти варианты. Должно работать.
Сложно сказать что у вас, без примеров.